# a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property 'Component.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have no idea what is going on, I am trying to follow a tutorial that was written in Unity 4 and a lot has changed. This is as far as I have gotten and now I am stuck.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;

    public static Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    private Vector3 input;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Unity's `GetComponent` function outside a function. Put it in a function and you should be fine. In this is case, it is appropriate to put it in a `Start()` or `Awake()` function.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;

    public static Rigidbody rb;
    private Vector3 input;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(input);
    }
}
```